# DataFrame organização de linhas e colunas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá,

tenho a seguinte situação:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


l=[]

l.append(('Mod1',0,70))
l.append(('Mod1',1,88))
l.append(('Mod1',2,97))
l.append(('Mod2',0,44))
l.append(('Mod2',1,93))
l.append(('Mod2',2,100))
l.append(('Mod3',0,99))
l.append(('Mod3',1,71))
l.append(('Mod3',2,33))
```

Eu gostaria que o Dataframe ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
   Mod1    Mod2    Mod3
0   70      44      99
1   88      93      71
2   97     100      33
```

onde 0,1,2 seria o índice
porém da forma  que fiz os Mod1,Mod2,Mod3 ficam em diferentes colunas

da forma que eu fiz:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=l)
df=df.transpose()
```

fica dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não estou entendendo o que está errado

Comment: Olá, eu editei a pergunta para mostrar da forma que está ficando do jeito que eu fiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código abaixo foi testado com o [pandas-1.0](/questions/tagged/pandas-1.0), e usando a função [**`pivot_table`** [Pandas-docs]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) permite converter o `dataframe` para o formato pretendido:

```
df.columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] #adicionados títulos às diferentes colunas
df = df.pivot_table(index=['col2'], columns='col1', values='col3').reset_index()
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df
```

`Out[11]:
    Mod1    Mod2    Mod3
0   70      44      99
1   88      93      71
2   97      100     33`

Answer (score 1):

Terceiro edit: acredito que agora o código consiga processar os dados da forma esperada, ou seja, com automatização da geração das listas e com inclusão correta de cada "Mod", independentemente da nomenclatura de cada string. Quanto ao problema da irregularidade da quantidade de dados por cada "Mod", utilizei o recurso de incluir o dado 0 em cada campo vazio (verifique se isto traz prejuízo para o processamento dos dados no seu caso).

Quarto edit: Havia um erro na lógica deste última versão postada, vou reenviar a versão que acredito que esteja funcionando adequadamente. Para organizar melhor a resposta, vou substituir as versões anteriores pelo código abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = {}
l = []
lista_mods = []
lista_valores = []
maximo = 0

l.append(('Mod1',0,70))
l.append(('Mod1',1,88))
l.append(('Mod1',2,97))
l.append(('Mod1',3,44)) # linha incluída para testar o funcionamento com diferentes quantidades de índices
l.append(('Mod2',0,44))
l.append(('Mod2',1,93))
l.append(('Mod2',2,100))
l.append(('Mod3',0,99))
l.append(('Mod3',1,71))
l.append(('Mod3',2,33))

for pos, c in enumerate(l):
    if l[pos][0] not in lista_mods:
        lista_mods.append(l[pos][0])

for pos, c in enumerate(lista_mods):
    for n in range(0, len(l)):
        if l[n][0] == c:
            lista_valores.append([])
            lista_valores[pos].append(l[n][2])

for c in lista_valores:
    if len(c) > maximo:
        maximo = len(c)

for pos, c in enumerate(lista_valores):
    while True:
        if len(c) < maximo:
            lista_valores[pos].append(0)
        else:
            break    

dados = dict(zip(lista_mods, lista_valores))
df = pd.DataFrame(dados)
print(df)
df.to_html('temp.html')
```

Comment: Olá, muito boa a solução, também estou no inicio de aprendizagem com o pandas.. Porém para encurtar o problema eu coloquei apenas do Mod1 ao Mod3, mas na verdade eu tenho até Mod98 em sequencia (Mod1..Mod98), e nesse caso fica um pouco complicado criar 98 listas.

Comment: Compreendi. Mas é sempre nesse padrão? Cada 'modN' tem sempre três dados respectivos?

Comment: Os nomes mudam, Mod1, Modulo30, Md15... n tem um padrão de nome, e são até 30 dados de cada um deles.

Comment: Eu até estava imaginando uma forma de automatizar essa criação das listas, mas como não tem um padrão específico (de nomenclatura e de quantidade de dados por cada "Mod"), não consigo pensar em uma saída simples. Acredito que o caminho correto seja pelas funções da biblioteca pandas mesmo, se eu encontrar algo acrescentarei aqui.

Comment: Alterei o código de acordo com os problemas apresentados, veja se desta forma o processamento dos dados fica correto. Novamente, considerando minhas limitações em relação à biblioteca pandas, tentei resolver as questões que surgiram pelas funções e métodos nativos do Python, é bem provável que haja solução melhor pelos recursos específicos da biblioteca.

Comment: Fiz uma nova retificação, pois a lógica da versão anterior estava errada.